# Access MatDrawer using ViewChild is throwing error in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, viewchild, mat-sidenav, mat-drawer

I'm trying to set the behavior of MatSideNav through component file using a property of type MatDrawer in Angular version 8

*TypeScript Code:*

```
// Declaration
@ViewChild('drawer', { static: false }) public drawer: MatDrawer;

// Toggle the Side Nav bar
showSideNav(): void {
    this.drawer.toggle();
}
```

*HTML Code:*

```
<mat-drawer-container>
      <mat-drawer #drawer>
        <div>Side nav bar content</div>
      </mat-drawer>
      <div>Main content</div>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

**Console Error:**

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.drawer is undefined"
```

Kindly assist me how to access the `MatDrawer` element using `@ViewChild`

Comment: set static to true, or add an *ngIf to the template (they mentioned this in the documentation but i cannot quite remember)

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli - Yes I tried it, it gives the same error.

Comment: Weird, it works for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyrccg?file=app/sidenav-drawer-overview-example.html

Comment: @yurzui - Still I'm getting the same error, kindly wait a moment I'll check and try to reproduce the same in StackBlitz.

Comment: Try: `@ViewChild(MatDrawer) public drawer: MatDrawer`

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha - The second param they made it mandatory.

Comment: @yurzui - Its working. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was the problem?

Comment: @yurzui - I given `id="drawer"`

Answer (score 5):

Change declaration  from

```
@ViewChild('drawer', { static: false }) public drawer: MatDrawer;
```

to

```
@ViewChild('drawer', { static: true }) public drawer!: MatDrawer;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was because I had not imported MatSidenavModule in my Angular module. I could still refer to MatDrawer without error because I had Material installed, but it was not in the module import list.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve similar issue by passing the mat-drawer / sidenav id in the child component using @Input decorator, so in case of OP's problem statement something like this might work.

```
// Declaration
@Input drawerHandler: MatDrawer;

// Toggle the Side Nav bar
showSideNav(): void {
    this.drawerHandler.toggle();
}
```

And in template pass this input id value using a property binding

```
<mat-drawer-container>
      <mat-drawer #drawer [drawerHandler]="drawer">
        <div>Side nav bar content</div>
      </mat-drawer>
      <div>Main content</div>
</mat-drawer-container>
```